# Normalized Coordinate system, Hermitian Cubic Shape function

Tags: finite-element, local-coordinates

How can I convert a local shape function given in terms of normalized/natural coordinates to global shape function in terms of x and y coordinate system in Hermitian cubic shape function.
Please explain using a 1 Dimensional problem.
What is a general expression for Hermitian cubic shape function.

Comment: Have you looked at other questions in this site? E.g.,  https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/27056/9667

Comment: How is it a "Matlab problem"?